# Every group is an F-algebra, but is every F-algebra (of the right signature) a group object?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, category-theory, solution-verification, functors

[Wikipedia's F-algebra page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-algebra) explains how, given

(1) a category $C$ of group objects with finite products / coproducts and a terminal object 1, and

(2) a group object $G \in Ob(C)$,

we can define an F-algebra $(G,\alpha)$ for the functor $F(X) = 1 + X + X \times X$ where $\alpha : 1 + G + G \times G \rightarrow G$ is defined by sending any elements of 1 to the identity of $G$ in the first part of the coproduct, elements of G are sent to inverses in the second part, and we have group multiplication in the third part.

**Question:**  Wikipedia actually leaves off the requirement that every object in $C$ be a group object, but I added that requirement to (1) because I don't know how to define $\alpha$ if I don't know a priori of inverse or multiplication maps.  Was I correct in assuming this added assumption is needed or is there a way to construct $\alpha$ even if I don't know that all objects are group objects beforehand?

Thanks so much for any input! :)

Answer (score 6):

I think you are misunderstanding the construction slightly. The construction is this: let $C$ be a category with finite products and coproducts (for me "finite" implies the empty case so this implies $C$ has an initial and terminal object), which in Wikipedia's example is just $\text{Set}$. Let $G$ be a group object in $C$. Then $G$ determines an $F$-algebra for the functor $F(X) = 1 + X + X^2$, *on $C$* (not on the category of group objects in $C$), where the three components of the map

$$(1 + G + G^2) \to G$$

are, respectively, the inclusion of the identity, the inverse map, and the multiplication map. This map is a morphism in $C$, not in the category of group objects in $C$, because the inverse and multiplication aren't group homomorphisms in general (in fact this is equivalent to the group being abelian).

It doesn't matter whether you know that any other object of $C$ is a group object; the construction is about a particular group object in $C$, namely $G$.

As for the question in your title, which you never ask in the body, no, being an $F$-algebra just means being an object equipped with three maps $1 \to G, G \to G, G^2 \to G$ and *no axioms* imposed on those maps. There is a version of this construction that is capable of imposing the group axioms and it involves taking $F$ to be a [monad](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monad) rather than just a functor.

Comment: I do misunderstand the construction but not in the way you describe.  I understand that wikipedia does not mention any category of group objects in C (this in fact is the very point of my question).  The usual statement I see is something like "A group is an F-algebra".  Wikipedia shows how this is the case by starting with a group and showing that it is an F-algebra.  However, my question is basically whether I can forgo discussing groups altogether and just use the arrived at functor F.  This doesn't seem to work though precisely because I have no idea that in an arbitrary...

Comment: ...category C (without imposing the extra constraint that every object is a group object), I have no idea that an inverse or multiplication map exist, which means I can't define $\alpha$ and hence I can't get the F-algebra.  This to me says that even though I have often read it said that "the functor captures the signature of the group", it actually doesn't because after specifying the functor, I can just choose any object and morphism pair to be an F-algebra but not all of those F-algebras will be groups.  So am I missing something or does the functor just not have enough data to actually...

Comment: define groups in a complete, self-contained manner (which would seem to defeat some of the usefulness of F-algebras)?

Comment: @wanderingmathematician: you seem to be asking two questions here. The first question seems to be about what happens if we don't start with a group object. Then, as you say, we haven't been supplied with a candidate for $\alpha$ so we can't build it. That's all. The second question is about the extent to which F-algebras capture groups. Then, as I described in my answer, the answer is "almost not at all"; we only get the signature but not any of the group axioms.

Comment: Said more formally, the Wikipedia article defines a functor from group objects in $C$ to $F$-algebras in $C$. This functor is fully faithful but it is very far from essentially surjective; $F$-algebras are much more general objects (again, none of the group axioms are imposed). This is not what people use $F$-algebras for, it was just an example. Again as I mentioned in my answer, if you want to capture groups you use a monad called the free group monad.

Comment: Yes, that's how we get F-algebras that aren't groups, which is what I've been saying. Maybe you're getting stuck on the meaning of "is." When people say that an X is a Y they don't mean to imply that all Ys are Xes. A square is a rectangle but not all rectangles are squares. (Really this "is" language is extremely ambiguous; formally we should be talking about forgetful functors.)

Comment: I understand that all F-algebras are not groups, but I was essentially asking if there is some class of F-algebras which is equal to the class of groups and which could be described purely in F-algebra terms (e.g. all F-algebras where $F(X) = 1 + X + X \times X$ and perhaps $C$ is a certain kind of category).  That seems not to be the case though, so then the statement "all groups are F-algebras" or even "all groups are F-algebras for the F given above" are really just the same kind of statements as "all groups are sets", which doesn't actually capture the structure of groups.  Is that right?

Comment: Phrased alternatively, I guess I was hoping for something like "a group is a category with one object where every morphism is an automorphism" type of characterization but using F-algebras

Comment: @wanderingmathematician: okay, it wasn't clear to me at all that that's what you were asking. It depends on what you mean by "purely in $F$-algebra terms." If you're asking "does there exist a functor $F$ such that $F$-algebras are equivalent to groups" then the answer is no and it shouldn't be hard to prove using the fact that for the initial $F$-algebra the map $F(X) \to X$ is an isomorphism but the initial group is the trivial group. If you're asking "for $F(X) = 1 + X + X^2$, does there exist an '$F$-algebraic characterization' of which $F$-algebras are groups" then I don't know.

Comment: The forgetful functor from groups to $F$-algebras is better than the forgetful functor from groups to sets; the former is fully faithful (as I've mentioned already) but the latter is only faithful. (See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stuff,+structure,+property for more on this.) And finally, as I've also mentioned already, if you want to capture groups precisely using a setup like this, you use monads, which have more structure that can capture the group axioms.